# With flickr API - is it possible to list only 10 item in the feed

Tags: javascript, ajax, flickr

I am using Flickr API to list some images as below and I am able to get them but I wanted to have only 10 or fewer items in the feed result. How to get less than 10 items.I did not see any limit parameter?

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=rat&format=json&callback=?
```

It returns 20 items, but I need 10 or less itmes.

Here is sample code:

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=rat&format=json&callback=?",function(json){
  console.log("done");
});

function jsonFlickrFeed(data) {
  

  console.log(data.items.length);
  for(var i=0;i<data.items.length; i++){
      console.log(data.items[i]['media']['m']);
  }
}
```

Also I would like to achieve this with native js ajax call without jQuery but in case of native I am getting into error block.

```js
var url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=rat&format=json&callback=?";

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(data);  
    }else {
       console.log("error"); 
    }
}
xhr.open("GET", url)
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Hi @Tranquillity, can you update your question with the code that you achieved?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I have updated the question with sample code, here you can see the length of the item is 20.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a limit parameter in the Flickr API Service page for method `https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne`.

[image]

However, you can limit the printed results in the for loop. Anyways, you'll keep getting all results from the `https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne` method in background.

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("form");
  form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    $.getJSON("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=rat&format=json&callback=?", window.jsonFlickrFeed);
    e.preventDefault();
  };
})();

window.jsonFlickrFeed = function(data) {
  var i, len = data.items.length, html = "", limit = document.getElementById("txtLimit").value * 1;
  for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    html += "<img src=\"";
    html += data.items[i].media.m;
    html += "\" />";
  }
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = html;
};
```

```css
#list {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#results img {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <label for="txtLimit">Limit:</label>
  <input id="txtLimit" min="0" type="number" value="0" />
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
  <hr />
  <div id="list"></div>
</form>
```

**Update:**

Why this works with jQuery and why not with JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest`?

Because `jQuery.getJSON()` is getting the resource like a script.
[image]

Also, there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response headers but in this case is not a problem. It's script that can be requested by using:

```
<script src="https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=rat&format=json&callback=?" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

See the `content-type: application/javascript;`.

[image]

The response of this url is a function named `jsonFlickrFeed(Object parameter)` where the parameter is an JSON (**J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation):

```
{
  "title": "Recent Uploads tagged rat",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/tags\/rat\/",
  "description": "",
  "modified": "2017-10-30T15:46:12Z",
  "generator": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com",
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "Garvey Fisherman",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/gid617\/37544497166\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4468\/37544497166_06b2812faa_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-10-06T16:05:11-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/gid617\/\">gid617<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/gid617\/37544497166\/\" title=\"Garvey Fisherman\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4468\/37544497166_06b2812faa_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"210\" alt=\"Garvey Fisherman\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>&quot;If it swims, I'll catch it!&quot;<br \/> This Garvey Fisherman is sure to always be found in or on the water. Fishing is more than his job, it's his passion! He dreams of walking into Kieg one day with the Kraaken on the end of his line!<br \/> <br \/> Overviews of the whole BoBS series: <a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/gid617\/37561290702\/in\/photostream\">(1)<\/a> <a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/gid617\/36923208713\/in\/photostream\">(2)<\/a><\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T15:46:12Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"gid617\")",
      "author_id": "82336002@N02",
      "tags": "lego minifigures eurobricks bobs eslandola corrington sea rat oleon"
    },
    {
      "title": "https:\/\/t.co\/jocRzPrIlh http:\/\/ift.tt\/2yXuiur",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/147697547@N08\/37332106894\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4493\/37332106894_e92604698f_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-10-30T07:55:49-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/147697547@N08\/\">rickylavendergold<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/147697547@N08\/37332106894\/\" title=\"https:\/\/t.co\/jocRzPrIlh http:\/\/ift.tt\/2yXuiur\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4493\/37332106894_e92604698f_m.jpg\" width=\"159\" height=\"240\" alt=\"https:\/\/t.co\/jocRzPrIlh http:\/\/ift.tt\/2yXuiur\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>via Tumblr <a href=\"http:\/\/ift.tt\/2zih52h\" rel=\"nofollow\">ift.tt\/2zih52h<\/a><\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T14:55:49Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"rickylavendergold\")",
      "author_id": "147697547@N08",
      "tags": "ratties ifttt facebookpages facebook page rat rats rattie fluff rattieflu"
    },
    {
      "title": "At the fetish market",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/carsten_tb\/24188861808\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4457\/24188861808_d542f1f308_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-01-09T10:28:22-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/carsten_tb\/\">10b travelling<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/carsten_tb\/24188861808\/\" title=\"At the fetish market\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4457\/24188861808_d542f1f308_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"At the fetish market\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>The Akodessawa Fetish Market or Marche des Feticheurs at Akodessawa, a district of Lom\u00e9, Togo in West Africa, is the world's largest vodou \/ vodoun\/ voodoo fetish market.<br \/> <br \/> The market features monkey heads, skulls, dead birds, crocodiles, skins and other products of dead animals. It is visited by healers \/ guerisseurs from around West Africa.<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T14:59:52Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"10b travelling\")",
      "author_id": "77334245@N00",
      "tags": "10btravelling 2017 africa african afrika afrique akodessewa akodessewafetishmarket carstentenbrink feticheurs fetishmarket genericplaces gulfofguinea iptcbasic lome lom\u00e9 marchedesfeticheurs otherkeywords places republic r\u00e9publiquetogolaise togo togolais togolaise togoland togolese westafrica africaine animal dead fetiches fetish guerisseur healer march\u00e9 market pigeon rat snakes tenbrink traditionalmedicine turtle vodou vodoun voodoo"
    },
    {
      "title": "https:\/\/t.co\/yrLeXdQYkh http:\/\/ift.tt\/2zQIggU",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/147697547@N08\/26261755469\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4488\/26261755469_bf3987f390_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-10-30T05:35:37-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/147697547@N08\/\">rickylavendergold<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/147697547@N08\/26261755469\/\" title=\"https:\/\/t.co\/yrLeXdQYkh http:\/\/ift.tt\/2zQIggU\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4488\/26261755469_bf3987f390_m.jpg\" width=\"160\" height=\"240\" alt=\"https:\/\/t.co\/yrLeXdQYkh http:\/\/ift.tt\/2zQIggU\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>via Tumblr <a href=\"http:\/\/ift.tt\/2gMmweo\" rel=\"nofollow\">ift.tt\/2gMmweo<\/a><\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T12:35:37Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"rickylavendergold\")",
      "author_id": "147697547@N08",
      "tags": "ratties ifttt facebookpages facebook page rat rats rattie fluff rattieflu"
    },
    {
      "title": "https:\/\/t.co\/Te2wafkGKL http:\/\/ift.tt\/2hmiyKj",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/147697547@N08\/38036736941\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4460\/38036736941_b4d6097e6f_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-10-30T04:35:07-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/147697547@N08\/\">rickylavendergold<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/147697547@N08\/38036736941\/\" title=\"https:\/\/t.co\/Te2wafkGKL http:\/\/ift.tt\/2hmiyKj\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4460\/38036736941_b4d6097e6f_m.jpg\" width=\"180\" height=\"240\" alt=\"https:\/\/t.co\/Te2wafkGKL http:\/\/ift.tt\/2hmiyKj\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>via Tumblr <a href=\"http:\/\/ift.tt\/2zRw1kd\" rel=\"nofollow\">ift.tt\/2zRw1kd<\/a><\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T11:35:07Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"rickylavendergold\")",
      "author_id": "147697547@N08",
      "tags": "ratties ifttt facebookpages facebook page rat rats rattie fluff rattieflu"
    },
    {
      "title": "http:\/\/ift.tt\/2yWEOlD",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/147697547@N08\/38035504481\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4459\/38035504481_17fc95cdbe_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-10-30T03:20:25-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/147697547@N08\/\">rickylavendergold<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/147697547@N08\/38035504481\/\" title=\"http:\/\/ift.tt\/2yWEOlD\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4459\/38035504481_17fc95cdbe_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"http:\/\/ift.tt\/2yWEOlD\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>via Tumblr <a href=\"http:\/\/ift.tt\/2gVsiy7\" rel=\"nofollow\">ift.tt\/2gVsiy7<\/a><\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T10:20:25Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"rickylavendergold\")",
      "author_id": "147697547@N08",
      "tags": "ratties ifttt facebookpages facebook page rat rats rattie fluff rattieflu"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/37981347146\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4514\/37981347146_ffa7f1418f_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T11:34:22-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/37981347146\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4514\/37981347146_ffa7f1418f_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:28Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/37981370436\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4494\/37981370436_e993b1100f_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T11:33:43-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/37981370436\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4494\/37981370436_e993b1100f_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:26Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/24182616908\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4462\/24182616908_fc758c60e9_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T11:02:37-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/24182616908\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4462\/24182616908_fc758c60e9_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"123\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:23Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/26258726769\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4462\/26258726769_94681d14e4_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T11:01:58-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/26258726769\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4462\/26258726769_94681d14e4_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:22Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/38034718591\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4502\/38034718591_6c6c464481_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T10:47:27-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/38034718591\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4502\/38034718591_6c6c464481_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:18Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/38034728141\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4499\/38034728141_e7a04cfd09_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T10:31:09-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/38034728141\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4499\/38034728141_e7a04cfd09_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:17Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/24182612888\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4448\/24182612888_6071699663_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T11:11:20-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/24182612888\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4448\/24182612888_6071699663_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"209\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:24Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/26258719859\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4481\/26258719859_77e62e29e3_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T11:20:02-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/26258719859\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4481\/26258719859_77e62e29e3_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:25Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/26258708999\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4485\/26258708999_68130d47d4_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T11:20:05-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/26258708999\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4485\/26258708999_68130d47d4_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:26Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/38004222102\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4510\/38004222102_ce27392ebd_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T10:29:36-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/38004222102\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4510\/38004222102_ce27392ebd_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:16Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/38004201422\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4497\/38004201422_fa17f93ed7_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T10:47:35-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/38004201422\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4497\/38004201422_fa17f93ed7_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:19Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/37326104584\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4504\/37326104584_6a1a8118c1_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T11:13:39-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/37326104584\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4504\/37326104584_6a1a8118c1_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"165\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:24Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/37326095364\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4476\/37326095364_d30e7e470a_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T11:39:55-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/37326095364\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4476\/37326095364_d30e7e470a_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"134\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:29Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    },
    {
      "title": "TRUCK'N",
      "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/37981363196\/",
      "media": {
        "m": "https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4455\/37981363196_209b6be505_m.jpg"
      },
      "date_taken": "2017-07-16T11:34:15-08:00",
      "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/wifithai\/\">*SIN CITY*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/wifithai\/37981363196\/\" title=\"TRUCK'N\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4455\/37981363196_209b6be505_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"TRUCK'N\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Australia<\/p>",
      "published": "2017-10-30T09:40:27Z",
      "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"*SIN CITY*\")",
      "author_id": "48055086@N08",
      "tags": "truck transport ford gmc dodge vehicle lowrider 7d canon rusty custom hotrod hotrods oldschool oldsmobile backtobrunswick kool cool australia americancarsinaustralia queensland nsw power horsepower chev chevy chevrolete 48 34 32 taillights international wheels ride rat rod usa kustom hot street carshow zephyr v8"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

So well, you need a function to call the url by using the script tag to execute the function `jsonFlickrFeed({})`.

**Demo: Native JavaScript + JSONP:**

```js
(function() {
  function request(url, callback) {
    var head = document.head, script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    head.appendChild(script);

    // Remove the script tag after it's loaded once.
    script.onload = function() {
      this.remove();
    };
    window[callback] = function(data) {
      var i, len = data.items.length,
        html = "",
        limit = document.getElementById("txtLimit").value * 1;
      for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        html += "<img src=\"";
        html += data.items[i].media.m;
        html += "\" />";
      }
      document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = html;
    };
  }


  var form = document.getElementById("form");
  form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=rat&format=json&callback=?";

    request(url, "jsonFlickrFeed"); // jsonFlickrFeed is the function which is returned from the URL.
  };



})();
```

```css
#list {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#results img {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="txtLimit">Limit:</label>
  <input id="txtLimit" min="0" type="number" value="0" />
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
  <hr />
  <div id="list"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Danny thanks for your reply and yes there is no limit parameter. I have another problem with this API. I do not want to use JQUERY and want to achieve with native AJAX XMLHttpRequestcall without JASONP. I am getting cross-domain issue if I try with XMLHttpRequest. Could you help me to see if you have same issue. If getJSON work why not XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: I have edited the question with native XMLHttpRequest call and in this case, I am getting into error block could you help me to debug why?

Comment: thanks a lot, now I got an endpoint without callback which returns json object https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=rat&format=json&nojsoncallback=1 but this does not work with native XMLHttpRequest(), could you propose some solution for this endpoint with native XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: When you are trying to get data from a url that belongs to another domain through `XMLHttpRequest` it needs to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response headers. I cant see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` settled in this endpoint.

Comment: I see now, it seems Flicker does not support native ajax call and Flicker server is not in our control so now we have to use either jsonp or jquery, isn't it? Do you recall any other possibility without jquery?

Comment: Yes, there is an option. Use this url https://crossorigin.me/https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=rat&format=json&nojsoncallback=1 in your `XMLHttpRequest` code. Check this https://crossorigin.me/. However is not guaranteed.

Comment: I tried and  https://crossorigin.me/https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=rat&format=json&nojsoncallback=1 gives 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: You should try with my demo. https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=rat&format=json&callback=? JavaScript and `JSONP`.